# To find the inverse function.

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-function, lambert-w

I am trying to find the inverse function of the following equation
$$f(x) = -x^2 {e^{-3x} \over 3} - 2x{e^{-3x} \over 9} - 2 {e^{-3x} \over 27} + {2 \over 27}$$
where $x \ge 0 $. 
I know that the above equation is one-one and onto but I am not able to find the inverse. I have typed my workout below. I hope someone can help me. Thank you!
$$f(x) = -9x^2 {e^{-3x} \over 27} - 6x{e^{-3x} \over 27} - 2 {e^{-3x} \over 27} + {2 \over 27}$$
$$(27 \times f(x)) = -9x^2 {e^{-3x} } - 6x{e^{-3x} } - 2 {e^{-3x} } + {2}$$
$$(27 \times f(x))- {2} = -9x^2 {e^{-3x} } - 6x{e^{-3x} } - 2 {e^{-3x} } $$
$$(27 \times f(x))- {2} = (-9x^2  - 6x - 2){e^{-3x} }  $$

Comment: Are you sure that the inverse is explainable with standard algebraic functions? Since it seems it is not to me.

Comment: First things first: Are you sure an inverse exists involving only elementary functions and Lambert W? I think you need what's discussed in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/217536)

Comment: If the quadratic factored as a square, we could continue though. Did you check for typos?

Comment: @Milten, thank you so much for your response but 
what do you mean by quadratic factored?

Comment: @JoBi I mean, if we had $(9x^2+6x+2) = (ax+b)^2$, it would be good. But we don't.  That's why I think there isn't a solution with only Lambert W, or that you made a typo. Where does the problem come from, and do you have a reason to believe a solution exists?

Comment: Are you sure that they do not ask for a series solution ?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=-x^2{e^{-3x}\over 3}-2x{e^{-3x}\over 9}-2{e^{-3x}\over 27}+{2 \over 27}$$

$y=f(x)$

$$-x^2{e^{-3x}\over 3}-2x{e^{-3x}\over 9}-2{e^{-3x}\over 27}+{2 \over 27}=y$$

**a)**

$$\left(y-{2\over 27}\right)(e^x)^3+{1\over 3}x^2+{2\over 9}x+{2\over 27}=0$$

We see, the equation can be rearranged to a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($x,e^x$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

For algebraic $y$, the equation cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).
It follows that the elementary function on the left-hand side of the equation cannot have elementary partial inverses over non-discrete domains.

**b)**

$x\to {t\over 3}$:
$$\left(y-{2\over 27}\right)e^t+{1\over 27}t^2+{2\over 27}t+{2\over 27}=0$$
$$-\frac{27y-2}{t^2+2t+2}e^t=1$$

We see, this equation cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W, but in terms of Generalized Lambert W:

$$\frac{y-2}{(t-(-1+i))(t-(-1-i))}e^t=-\frac{1}{27}$$
$$t=W\left(^{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2}_{-1+i,-1-i};-\frac{1}{27}\right)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{3}W\left(^{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2}_{-1+i,-1-i};-\frac{1}{27}\right)$$

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $x$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange:

$$f(x)=-\frac{x^2}3e^{-3x}-\frac{2x}9e^{-3x}-\frac2{27}e^{-3x}+\frac2{27}=\frac2{27}-\frac2{27}e^{-3x}\left((3x)^3+2(3x)^2+2\cdot3x\right)=\frac2{27}(1-Q(3,3x))$$

using the [regularized gamma function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gammaregularized). Now apply Mathematica’s [inverse gamma regularized](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gammaregularized):

$$f(x)=-\frac{x^2}3e^{-3x}-\frac{2x}9e^{-3x}-\frac2{27}e^{-3x}+\frac2{27}\implies f^{-1}(x)=\frac13Q^{-1}\left(3,1-\frac{27x}2\right)$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot+%7Bx%2C1%2F3+inversegammaregularized%283%2C+1+-+27%2F2+%28-x%5E2%2F3+e%5E%28-3x%29-2x%2F9+e%5E%28-3x%29-2%2F27+e%5E%28-3x%29%2B2%2F27%29%29%7D). $f^{-1}(x)$ is the [quantile](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=percentile+gamma+distribution+alpha%3D3%2Cbeta%3D1%2F3) of a gamma distribution with shape parameters $\alpha=3,\beta=\frac13$. Click “Show formulas” in the last link.